# ASP.NET Core Web API - Export to excel is limited to only the current page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, pagination, excelpackage

I have this code in ASP.NET Core Web API. The user can use search query and then export to excel or just export to excel straight. It has maximum of ten (10) records per page.

However, I observed that only the current page (not more than 10 records) is exported to excel. Even if the Search query gives 3 pages with 30 records or as the case may be.

Kindly help resolve this.

MAIN CODE:

Models:

PagingDto:

```
public class PagingDto
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

PagingFilter:

```
public class PagingFilter : PagingDto
{
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }  
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } 
}
```

PageResult:

```
public class PageResult<T>
{
    public T PageItems { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Response:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }

    public Response(int statusCode, bool success, string msg, T data, EnumResponseCodes responseCode, string responseDescription)
    {
        Data = data;
        Successful = success;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = msg;
        ResponseCode = responseCode.GetStringValue();
        ResponseDescription = responseDescription;
    }

    public Response()
    {
    }

    public static Response<T> Success(string successMessage, T data, EnumResponseCodes responseCode, int statusCode = 200)
    {
        return new Response<T> { 
            Successful = true, 
            Message = successMessage, 
            Data = data, 
            StatusCode = statusCode,
            ResponseCode = responseCode.GetStringValue(),
            ResponseDescription = responseCode.ToString()
        };
    }
    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

Repository:

GetMandateQueryAsync:

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<Mandate>> GetMandateQueryAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        try
        {
            var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
            var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
            var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();

            if (loggedUserRoleName == "Merchant")
            {
                merchantId = _dbContext.Merchants.Where(u => u.User.UserName == userName).Select(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                merchantId = _dbContext.MerchantUsers.Where(u => u.User.UserName == userName).Select(m => m.MerchantId).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            IQueryable<Mandate> query = _dbContext.Mandates
                        .Where(x => x.MerchantId == merchantId)
                        .Include(x => x.MandateDetails)
                        .Include(x => x.MandateApproval)
                        .Include(x => x.MandateCancellationRequest)
                        .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                        .ThenInclude(m => m.User);

            // Apply search filtering
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery))
            {
                query = query
                    .Where(m =>
                    m.Merchant.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    m.ReferenceNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    m.DrAccountNumber.Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    (m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Monthly ? "monthly"
                      : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Quarterly ? "quarterly"
                      : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.BiAnnual ? "biannual"
                      : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Yearly ? "yearly"
                      : "unknown"
                      ).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                    m.BankBranch.BranchName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    m.Amount.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    (m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.PendingApproval ? "pending approval"
                      : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Declined ? "declined"
                      : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Approved ? "approved"
                      : "unknown"
                      ).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    );
            }

            // Apply date range filtering
            if (filter.StartDate.HasValue && filter.EndDate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(m => m.CreatedAt >= filter.StartDate.Value && m.CreatedAt <= filter.EndDate.Value);
            }

            // Apply sorting
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SortBy))
            {
                switch (filter.SortBy)
                {
                    case "ReferenceNumber":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.ReferenceNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.ReferenceNumber);
                        break;
                    case "DrAccountNumber":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.DrAccountNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.DrAccountNumber);
                        break;
                    case "BranchName":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName);
                        break;
                    case "Amount":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.Amount) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Amount);
                        break;
                    case "MandateApprovalStatus":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus);
                        break;
                    case "CreatedAt":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.CreatedAt) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
            }
            return query;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while retrieving Mandates.", ex);
        }
    }
```

MerchantMandateService:

```
    public async Task<Response<byte[]>> ExportMandateToExcelAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        try
        {
            var auditReportsResponse = await GetMandateAsync(filter);
            var auditReports = auditReportsResponse.Data.PageItems;

            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
            var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Mandate Reports");

            // Title
            var title = "Reports";
            var titleCell = worksheet.Cells["A1:K1"]; // Adjust the range based on the number of columns
            titleCell.Merge = true;
            titleCell.Value = title;
            titleCell.Style.Font.Size = 16;
            titleCell.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            titleCell.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            titleCell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
            titleCell.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            titleCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

            // Headers
            var headers = new List<string>
            {
                "S.No.",
                "Merchant Name",
                "Reference Number",
                "Customer Account No.",
                "Branch",
                "Payment Frequency",
                "Start Date",
                "End Date",
                "Amount",
                "Approval Status",
                "Action Date"
            };
            // Set header values
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Value = headers[i];
                worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
            }

            // Populate data rows
            var row = 3;
            var serialNumber = 1;
            foreach (var report in auditReports)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = serialNumber;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = report.Merchant.MerchantName;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = report.ReferenceNumber;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = report.DrAccountNumber;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = report.BankBranch.BranchName;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = report.PaymentFrequency;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = report.StartDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value = report.EndDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value = report.Amount.ToString("N2");
                worksheet.Cells[row, 10].Value = report.MandateApprovalStatus;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 11].Value = report.CreatedAt?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? string.Empty;

                row++;
                serialNumber++;
            }

            // Auto-fit columns
            worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

            var excelBytes = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

            return new Response<byte[]>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Successful = true,
                Data = excelBytes,
                Message = "Successful.",
                ResponseCode = EnumResponseCodes.SUCCESS.GetStringValue(),
                ResponseDescription = EnumResponseCodes.SUCCESS.ToString()
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred.");
            return new Response<byte[]>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Successful = false,
                Message = "An error occurred.",
                ResponseCode = EnumResponseCodes.FAILED.GetStringValue(),
                ResponseDescription = EnumResponseCodes.FAILED.ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<MandateListDto>>>> GetMandateAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = await _unitOfWork.MerchantMandates.GetMandateQueryAsync(filter);

            var totalRecords = await query.CountAsync();
            var item = await query.PaginationAsync<Mandate, MandateListDto>(filter.PageNumber, filter.PageSize, _mapper);

            var pageResult = new PageResult<IEnumerable<MandateListDto>>
            {
                PageItems = item.PageItems,  // Update this line
                CurrentPage = filter.PageNumber,
                PageSize = filter.PageSize,
                NumberOfPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / filter.PageSize),
                TotalRecord = totalRecords
            };

            return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<MandateListDto>>>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Successful = true,
                Data = pageResult,
                Message = "All Mandates Retrieved Successfully",
                ResponseCode = EnumResponseCodes.SUCCESS.GetStringValue(),
                ResponseDescription = EnumResponseCodes.SUCCESS.ToString()
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports.");
            return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<MandateListDto>>>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Successful = false,
                Message = "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports.",
                ResponseCode = EnumResponseCodes.FAILED.GetStringValue(),
                ResponseDescription = EnumResponseCodes.FAILED.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(ApiRoutes.Merchant.GetMandates)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllMandateAsync([FromQuery] PagingFilter filter, [FromQuery] bool exportToExcel = false)
    {
        if (exportToExcel)
        {
            var response = await _merchantMandateService.ExportMandateToExcelAsync(filter);

            if (response.Successful)
            {
                var fileBytes = response.Data;
                var fileName = $"MandateReports_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";

                return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(response.StatusCode, response.Message);
            }
        }
        var result = await _merchantMandateService.GetMandateAsync(filter);
        return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
    }
```

Comment: this line: "query.PaginationAsync<Mandate, MandateListDto>(filter.PageNumber, filter.PageSize, _mapper);" Suggests that there will be a limit used... (one page of results is returned from the DB)  So send/resolve the full query to the export to xls function if you want all page's results.

Comment: @pcalkins - Based on my code, what do I write there. Kindly give examples

Comment: I think you'd want this line: var auditReportsResponse = await GetMandateAsync(filter); to be calling something like "GetMandateFullResultsForExcelAsync(filter);"  ..don't call the pagination method in there as it will probably limit the results to a single page.  (alternatively you could change the filter to show all pages I suppose, but don't know the whole flow here...)